# Umbraco 7: create menu datatype with submenus

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

How can I create a navigation menu data type with submenu items so that I can create it in the back office with properties like text, href, optional image? Something like dropdown multiple.
I've installed Umbraco 7.1.5 with NuGet in VS2013 and using Razor syntax.
**EDIT:**
Is it possible to create an object of type menu and edit it in the back-end's UI, for a non-developer. The user should add as many items or sub items as needed with those properties, with a plus sign. I've found [this](http://imulus.github.io/Archetype/) property editor. Is this possible using this property editor?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Partial View (in the back-end under the SETTINGS section).  If you create a new partial view, one of the pre-created snippets will be "navigation".

Then use some CSS menu (you e.g. created yourself or found on google), and try to match the navigation HTML to that of the CSS menu.

To include the partial view in the template just use

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfThePartialWithoutExtention")
```

Comment: What I want to do is to make an editable menu from the back-end with with properties like text, href, optional image, and then just to add or edit menu items from content section.

Comment: If you start with the description I gave above, you already have text and href.  Concerning the image: add an extra property on every node which will appear in the menu and change the Partial View appropriatly.

Comment: In this way the menu is created from the content tree, my question is if it is possible to create an object of type menu and edit it in the back-end's UI, for a non-developer. The user should add as many items or sub items as needed with those properties, with a plus sign. I've found [this](http://imulus.github.io/Archetype/) property editor. Do you think this is possible with this property editor?

Comment: It would be possible with a property editor (if you find one).  I don't know by heart a propertyeditor which can create trees.  If you create a new root node next to the HOME, then you can create your menu next to the content tree.