# Umbraco 7: Create an object of type menu and edit it in the back-end's UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I've installed Umbraco 7.1.5 using NuGet in VS2013 and using Razor syntax in my Views. I know that we can create a navigation menu from the document tree, but:
**Q:** Is it possible to create an object of type menu and edit it in the back-end's UI so that a non-developer could add as many items or sub items to the menu as needed with properties like text, href and optional image, with a plus sign. How can this be done? / or is this possible using [this](http://imulus.github.io/Archetype/) property editor?

Comment: Do you want the items to be visible in frontend? You could create a new Document Type called Menu Item with all the properties you want, and then create a new Menu Item List in Content, and then query this list from your razor file.

Comment: @Morton, that's what i suggested alex87 also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445890/umbraco-7-create-menu-datatype-with-submenus  I guess alex87 wants only to use a propertyEditor to build up a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course and you already have answered half your own question, but no you wouldn't need a plugin. The solution is very straightforward.

1. You create your MenuItem doc type, and in the "structure" tab allow MenuItem objects to be created under MenuItem objects.
2. You create somewhere in your content tree to allow editors to create their menu structures. I like to have a "site settings" node that things like site config, promos and other non-content items can be grouped.
3. Start creating your MenuItem tree.
4. In your razor, look for the root of the MenuItem tree and traverse down the tree using  some self-referential code like you would to create a site map. Something like *:

   ```
   @helper traverse(IPublishedContent node)
   {
       <ul>
       @foreach (var item in node.Children)
       {
           <li>
             <a href="@item.GetPropertyValue("menuItemHref")">
                 @item.GetPropertyValue("menuItemText")
             </a>

             @traverse(item)

           </li>
       }
       </ul>
   }

   <div class="menuItemTree"> 
       @traverse(@parentOfrootMenuItem)
   </div>
   ```

* Repurposed from our.umbraco.org